# Access input text from dynamically created input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build an online exam system. To make question paper i am creating two types of input fields dynamically. One is for question, and another is for options of the question. My jquery codes

```
<div id="q_paper"></div>
<br/><button type="button" id="go2">Ok</button>

for(var i=0;i<total_question;i++){
                var nw="<div class='q'>("+(i+1)+".)<textarea class='text_area'>Question"+(i+1)+"</textarea><br/>";
                for(var j=0;j<option_number;j++){
                    nw+="<input type='radio'/><input type='text' class='opt' value='option"+(j+1)+"' onfocus='this.value="+null+"'/>"+'<br/>';
                }
                nw+="</div>";
                $("#q_paper").append(nw);
            }

            $(".text_area").click(function(){
                $(this).text("");
            });
```

But i cann't access the input text from the both input field fields. I have tried a number of times but failed. How to get input text **when a ok button is clicked ?**

Comment: whats your code to get the text

Comment: How are you trying to access the input? Consider to use the `Delegated events` version of `on` function when creating elements `on-the-fly`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Where is your ok button and how are you handling the click to get the input?

Comment: I have edited my codes. can u say now?

Comment: where is `option_number` defined and set?

Comment: @alex amtho, i didn't give the code of option_number, but its ok and has a value that i can get. But but i dont get, why it is downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have use event delegation .on() function to access dynamically added content.. Here is the example to achieve that, hope this help:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#go2', function(){
        $('input.opt').each(function(){
              alert($(this).val());
         });

    }}

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: i can get input from 2nd input filed. pls edit answer how to get from 1st input field using class text_area. its not working just changing the class name

Comment: yeah, i got answer. Thank u